# Adding self-signed certificate to Heroku app

Tags: ssl, heroku, self-signed

I am trying to add a self-signed certificate to one of my apps on Heroku. I have followed the guides from the Dev Center.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

After I have generated the self-signed cert I try to add the cert by
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key

And get the error message:
Resolving trust chain... failed
!    No certificate given is a domain name certificate.

I am not sure what that means or how to fix the problem.

Comment: what's the output for `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in server.crt`?

Comment: subject= /C=US/ST=Texas/L=Frisco/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

Comment: So you have no CN? You have to set the CN to the domain you're issuing the certificate for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the CN to the domain you're issuing the certificate for.

Comment: E.g.: for my site, when queried for the CN it looked like this with my answer included: `Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:my-site.herokuapp.com`